# problema a enviar valores de uma route para outra

Tags: node.js, express.js

Eu estou a fazer um sistema de login com mysql
não estou a conseguir passar o valores de route para outra
eu quero passar da router login para router users
segue-se o codigo

```
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [username], function(err, rows, fields) {
     if (err) {
     appData.error = 1;
     appData['data'] = 'Error Occured!';
     res.status(400).json(appData);
     } else {
     if (rows.length > 0) {
     if (rows[0].password == password) {

    if (rows[0].nivel== 1) {

       res.redirect(307, '/Administration');
    //eu quero passar o username/nivel para /Administration
  res.send(username);
    }else if (rows[0].nivel== 2) {
       res.redirect(307, '/Users');

    }
    else if (rows[0].nivel== 3) {
       res.redirect(307, '/usersvip');

    }
    else if (rows[0].nivel== 4) {
       res.redirect(307, '/moderador');

    }
    else if (rows[0].nivel== 2) {
       res.redirect(307, '/activar');

    }
    else {
         res.redirect(307, '/banned');
    }
```

a pagina de onde quero receber os valores

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('Administration/index', { title: 'Home'});

});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Você quer passar dados no redirect()? Se for isso eu penso em query, mas esse não é o melhor caminho.

Comment: o quero fazer é o login é feito com sucesso ou não se for com sucesso se for nivel 1 vai para uma pagina 2 para outra passando os valores eu em php usava session_regenerate_id();
  $member = $result -> fetch_assoc();
  $_SESSION['SESS_NIVEL'] = $member['nivel'];
  $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'] = $member['mail']; não existe o mesmo metado mas para nodejs com o expresso

Comment: Então eu aconselho você dar uma olhada em [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session). Esse tipo validação fica mais simples com uso de session e middleware de validação de session. [Github](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Comment: Olha podes fazer um simples exemplo onde e enviado um valor do login para user usando sessões e que eu não estou a conseguir

Comment: Não posso responder sua pergunta, ficaria fora de escopo e me negativariam, mas da uma olhada nesse exemplo simples que ta no meu [Github](https://github.com/andersonmendesdev/passport-login). Outro exemplo um pouco mais sofisticado [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/andersonmendesdev/node-authentication/src)

Comment: no teu projecto no github voce usas esta dependencias "dependencies": {"bcrypt": "^3.0.0","body-parser": "^1.18.3","ejs": "^2.6.1","express": "^4.16.3","express-session": "^1.15.6","mongoose": "^5.2.4","passport": "^0.4.0",passport-local": "^1.0.0" },"devDependencies": {"nodemon": "^1.18.2" } mas eu uso estas "dependencies": {"body-parser": "~1.13.2","cookie-parser": "~1.3.5","cors": "^2.8.4","debug": "~2.2.0","express": "~4.13.1","express-session": "^1.15.6","jade": "~1.11.0","jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0","morgan": "~1.6.1","mysql": "^2.16.0","serve-favicon": "~2.3.0" o que tenho que mudar
  }

Comment: para que funcione com o teu exemplo que tens no teu github so tenho que instalar o estas dependencias certo "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
},

Comment: Isso exatamente. Se der um npm install ou yarn ele instala tudo automaticamente.

Comment: Esse exemplo usa mongodb como database.

Comment: em relação ao que tens no controller tenho que alterar alguma coisa é no auth.js, home.js,user.js que uso mysql estou a começar com o nodejs eu geralmente uso o php ou so no tens na pasta models é que tenho alteral

Comment: Então oq tem no controller desse ai é so para mongodb se tu quer manipular mysql indico outra pasta minha, [Mysql](https://bitbucket.org/andersonmendesdev/node-mysql/src/master/)
ou usando  [sequelize](https://bitbucket.org/andersonmendesdev/node-sequelize/src/master/), pega firme nos estudos, para mysql eu comecei usando a dependecia nativa depois passei a usar sequelize.

Comment: qual é diferença de usar a conneção com a base de dados na app.js ou numa route

Comment: Em temos de uso na api nenhum, mas em termos de projeto a estrutura fica mais organizada, já imaginou 7 bases dados configuradas na main? No inicio eu configurava de qualquer jeito, hj eu uso modelo OOD.

Comment: ou seja melhor é chamar na app eu  criei dois ficheiros um para conneção e outro que grava a coneção

Comment: Olha não estou a conseguir usar o integrar o teus dois exemplos o auth com passaport e o pessoas podias me ajudar sempre podes usar o pastben ou criar um repositório no github eu apenas preciso de um simples exemplo

Comment: se for possivel usa com session e passar valores de route para outra e obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Acessa esse link aqui https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81195/discussion-about-question-ams-and-rsrd

Comment: Segue https://github.com/andersonmendesdev/exampleLogin

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: ja agora uso o bcrypt para increpitar a minha password

Comment: Boa, cuidado com as perguntas fora de contexto ou vagas demais o pessoal te negativa e tu acaba perdendo direito de perguntar. Se tu tiver skype add la ai hora q tiver duvida tu me pergunta skype: anderson.mendes88

Comment: ja estou no skype obrigada

Comment: topico pode ser fechado problema foi resolvido obrigada AMS pela ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui desta maneira

```
const authenticateUser = async (connection,  req, res) => {

  const user = await User.findUser(connection, req.body.username)
    if(!user){
        return res.render('login/login',{error: true})
    }
    if(!await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)){
        return res.render('login/login', {error: true})
}
    else{
      if(user.user_type_id==1){
        req.session.user = user
        res.locals.user = user
      res.redirect('/Administration/index');
    }else if(user.user_type_id==2){
      req.session.user = user
      res.locals.user = user
      res.redirect('/Administration/index');
    }else if(user.user_type_id==3){
      req.session.user = user
      res.locals.user = user
      res.redirect('/Administration/index');
    }else if(user.user_type_id==4){
      req.session.user = user
      res.locals.user = user
      res.redirect('/Administration/index');
      }
      else if(user.user_type_id==5){
        req.session.user = user
        res.locals.user = user
        res.redirect('/Administration/index');
    } else {
        console.log("banned");
    }



  }
}
```